# List dont save correctly values if i inizializate the temp variable out

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a problem with Lists in Java and Android. I read and save all user contacts in a List with this code:

```
List<ContactInfo> list = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();

do {
    contactInfo.name   = people.getString(indexName);
    contactInfo.phone  = people.getString(indexNumber);

    list.add(contactInfo);

} while (people.moveToNext());
```

In the do-while everything is OK, name and phone is correct but the list don't save correctly values (To be specific, it saves correctly the values but out of the do-while every value is replaced with the last inserted value).
It just saves the last contact in every position but if I try to debug what he add in every position during the do-while it says the correct values.

It's the code I used to check every item out of the do-while

```
int i = 0;
for(ContactInfo info : list)
{
    Log.d(newMessage.TAG, "contactInfo(" + i + "): name = " + info.name + " ; phone = " + info.phone);
    ++i;
}
```

I have fixed the problem with this edit:

```
do {
    contactInfo = new ContactInfo();

    contactInfo.name   = people.getString(indexName);
    contactInfo.phone  = people.getString(indexNumber);

    list.add(contactInfo);

} while (people.moveToNext());
```

It creates a different instance of ContactInfo every contact but why don't work if I create one out of the do-while?

And, if I create a different instance for every contact it can cause memory-leak / out-of-memory or something similar if number of contacts are too much? Or maybe just make the application slow, because the GC should clear the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that the object will be the same when you do it your way. The objectreference of the object is the same all the time, so the only object which is added it the first one.

Greets

Comment: Oh, you are right! My mind now understand why.. list.add copy the reference to the object. thanks.. stupid question. sometimes my mind don't remember stupid things :|